# MS Access parameter: enter multiple values or leave blank to return all records

Tags: ms-access, parameters, ms-access-2010

I have a table with a `CONTRACT` column:

```
+----+----------+
| ID | CONTRACT |
+----+----------+
|  1 | C2017-01 |
|  2 | C2017-02 |
|  3 | C2017-03 |
|  4 | C2017-04 |
|  5 | C2017-05 |
+----+----------+
```

I have a query that has a **parameter** as the criteria for the `CONTRACT` column:

```
[Enter a contract number (example: C2017-01):]
```

The parameter allows users enter a single contract number.

Alternatively, users can opt to leave the parameter blank and hit OK. This is allows users to output all contracts, without entering their numbers.

**Question:**

Instead of just entering a single contract, users need to be able to enter **multiple contracts**.

Example:

`C2017-02,C2017-03,C2017-04`

Users still need to be able to do the alternative, which is to list all contracts, without knowing/entering their numbers.

How can I do this?

It would be preferable to keep this functionality in a parameter in a query, not in a custom form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE Contract Like "*" & [Enter Contract Number(s)] & "*" OR [Enter Contract Number(s)] Like "*" & [Contract] & "*"
```